# Most efficient algorithm for navigating a 3D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, godot

**TLDR: I need to average the values of all the surrounding coordinates for a specific coordinate for every coordinate in a 3D array**

I am making a simplistic weather simulating program in Godot C# and have run into a few problems along the way.

One of the biggest problems I have encountered is performance, along with a few other things. To simulate air flow, I have a 3D array containing direction (Vector3 objects) for each coordinate. To simulate the airflow, I set each voxel’s direction to the average of the directions of the surrounding voxels.

Each voxel has a pressure value, and a voxel transfers pressure scaled by the magnitude (speed) of the wind direction to the voxels the wind direction is pointing to. For example if a voxel at (x,y,x) has a direction of (1,1,1), the voxel at (x+1,y+1,z+1) will have its pressure set to `(x+1,y+1,z+1).pressure + direction.project(Vector3(x+1,y+1,z+1)).length() * (x,y,z).pressure`

A voxel will also add Vector3’s pointing towards neighboring voxels if the pressure difference is not 0. The length of these vectors will be scaled by the pressure difference.

There are a bunch of other properties that need to be averaged up such as temperature, humidity, density, etc.
The real issue is iterating through a 3D array in a way that is fast, very fast. The method I am using at the moment has ***six*** nested for loops: Three for iterating over each voxel in the array, and three for iterating over the neighboring voxels within a range of -1 to 1 in each direction. I want to simulate a 16x16x16 area, but this algorithm requires me to do 16x16x16x27 iterations every game tick, rendering the application unplayable.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Hint: You have to visit each voxel at least once. You want to ensure you visit each voxel ONLY once. As you visit it, write relevant info into another data structure then perform the average calculation in steps. E.g. for an interior voxel, you know each surrounding one will contribute 1/6 of its value to the average.

Comment: Interesting….. So maybe I should add 1/27th (it checks a 3x3x3 area around each voxel) of the voxel’s direction to the surrounding voxels?

Comment: Yeah if you include diagonals. Keep in mind voxels on the edge don't have as many neighbors. Not sure how you want to model that.

Comment: Btw I’m still a little new to C# so idk how much of a difference it makes, but wouldn’t just setting each surrounding voxel’s data individually have the same performance impact as another set of three nested loops inside the main three for loops loop?

Comment: I don't know what your exact looping logic looks like, but nested loops often point to less-than-ideal performance. Why don't you try an experiment where you just increment a counter each time your inner loop is run and compare that counter's value to the total number of voxels?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your nested loops are accessing memory in order of the memory's physical location. A 3D array is just a 1D array with some extra strides and offsets that occur behind the scenes.  If your array is organized as voxels[x, y, z], then your final nested loop should be the z loop. If you prefer to access voxels in a different pattern, then you can populate your array differently to accommodate the other pattern, such as voxels[z, y, x].

Second, try to eliminate repeat access of array locations on different loops. If you access a location on one loop and you plan to access it again on the next, try saving the info to a local variable and test to see if it improves speed.

Third, see if you can reduce the number of calculations. For example, if you are calculating an average of all variables in a 3x3x3 grid and then incrementing the location and repeating, you can try saving a running sum. Then on the next loop subtract the 3x3 section you no longer need, add the new 3x3 section, and then divide to get your new average.

On a side note, maybe your example is truncated or conceptual, but it doesn't look like you are actually averaging the values of all surrounding voxels. Each voxel will be surrounded by a 3x3x3 array of voxels (so 26 adjacent voxels when excluding the center voxel). If we exclude corners, there are still 6 adjacent voxels.

Comment: Thanks! I’m currently looping over the array in the way it was filled out: x,y,z. I’m not sure if I’m following you on your second and third points. I think saving voxels as local variables would use a lot of memory. I intend on scaling this up to larger arrays. And when you say I should make a running sum then subtract the unused 3x3, what do you mean by that?

Comment: For point 2, you can create local variables that gets replaced by each subsequent loop, For example, instead of doing something like "point[x, y, z-1] + point[x, y, z] + point[x, y, z+1]" we can offset the reference z by 1 and instead use point[x, y, z-2] + point[x, y, z-1] + point[x, y, z]" so we are only looking backwards and not forwards. Then we can create variables like ZMinus1 and ZMinus2 (forgive the terrible variable names). Then each loop use "ZMinus2 + ZMinus1 + point[x, y, z]". Then set "ZMinus2 = ZMinus1; ZMinus1 = point[x, y, z];" So you recycle the same variables each loop.

Comment: For point 3, look for ways to reduce operations, including using previous calculations to complete future calculations. For example, if you need a running sum of 5 numbers (let's use [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] for our data) you can say sum1 = 1+2+3+4+5 and sum2 = 2+3+4+5+6, etc. Or you could say sum2 = sum1-1+6 (subtracting the first data point and adding the 6th data point). Next, sum3 = sum2-2+7, etc. This removes 3 operations from each loop. Over 10,000 loops it removes 30,000 operations, etc.